# How can I instantiate an array of Stacks of type int?

Tags: java, arrays, stack, wildcard, towers-of-hanoi

I am trying to create an array of stacks, in which each stack within the array is of type `int`.

If I create the array like this:  `Stack<Integer>[] numbers = new Stack<Integer>[3];` , there is the compile error  "`Cannot create a generic array of Stack<Integer>`". So, I am trying to create the array of Stacks with the wildcard type instead of `Integer`,  and it then does *not* have this error.

However, if I then try to push an `int` into one of the stacks (of wildcard "`?`" type) like this:  `this.numbers[stackIndex].push(i);` , there is the compile error  "`The method push(capture#1-of ?) in the type Stack<capture#1-of ?> is not applicable for the arguments (int)`".

So, how can I properly instantiate an array of Stacks of type `int`? As of now I am not able to perform push/pop operations on these Stacks...

---

My reasoning in this is an attempt to program the Tower of Hanoi game. I wanted each of the three rods to be a `Stack` of type `int`, each ring to be represented as an `int`, and the three rods together to be contained as an array of the three Stacks.

---

Here is some example code:

```
import java.util.Stack;

public class StackTest {

    Stack<?>[] numbers;

    public StackTest(int stackLength) {
        this.numbers = new Stack<?>[stackLength];
    }

    public void fillStack(int stackIndex, int numRings) {
        for (int i = numRings; i >= 0; i--) {

            // this statement has a compile error!
            this.numbers[stackIndex].push(i);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numberOfRods = 3;
        StackTest obj = new StackTest(numberOfRods);

        int rodNumber = 0, numberOfRings = 4;
        obj.fillStack(rodNumber, numberOfRings);
    }
} // end of StackTest
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to be a raw `Stack[]` or you can use `List<Stack<YourClass>> lstStack = new ArrayList<Stack<YourClass>>()`.

In this case, I would prefer to use

```
List<Stack<Integer>> lstStack = new ArrayList<Stack<Integer>>(stackLength);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply! However, when I change it to a raw `Stack[]` I get the warning "`Stack is a raw type. References to generic type Stack<E> should be parameterized`". Is there a way to avoid this warning?

Comment: @IanCampbell yes, use the second way.

Comment: Thanks again @Luiggi, however when I try this the second way I get the compile error "`The type List is not generic; it cannot be parameterized with arguments <Stack<Integer>>"`.

Comment: @IanCampbell are you sure you're using `java.util.List`?

Comment: Ah, thanks @Luiggi! Eclipse opted that I import `java.awt.List` before `java.util.List`, in which was *not* working. `java.util.List` *is* working though, thanks again!

Comment: @IanCampbell don't forget to mark this post as the answer if it helped you.

Comment: Right right, thanks again @Luiggi. Hey why is polymorphism being used here, where it is of type `List` and using the `ArrayList` constructor?

Comment: @IanCampbell please refer to [What does it mean to “program to an interface”?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/383947/1065197)

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be:

```
public class StackInteger extends Stack<Integer> {
}
```

And then:

```
StackInteger[] numbers = new StackInteger[3];
```

Or even:

```
Stack<Integer>[] numbers = new StackInteger[3];
```

Comment: Thanks @sp00m, this is interesting, however when I do this I am getting the warning "`The serializable class StackInteger does not declare a static final serialVersionUID field of type long`" on the class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you should push an `Integer` rather than an `int`:

```
this.numbers[stackIndex].push(Integer.valueOf(i));
```

Comment: I like this solution, however when I change line 5 to `Stack<Integer> numbers;` and line 8 to `this.numbers = new Stack[stackLength];`, I get the warning "`Type safety: The expression of type Stack[] needs unchecked conversion to conform to Stack<Integer>[]`".